# vmware workstation 12pro cant turn on vm

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

when turning on vm a message shows

VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.

The VMX process exited prematurely.

already tried to restart authorization service and workstation service but didnt work.

this is extremely urgent. pls help.

Comment: it happened recently and no change has been made.

Answer (score 0):

it was fixed after repairing workstation via feature and program